# Error with GraphQL Rails (GraphQL::ObjectType can't define '“Query”'")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I'm trying to create use GraphQL with Rails and have been following a couple of guides, the latest of which is: https://medium.com/@UnicornAgency/you-should-be-using-graphql-a-ruby-introduction-9b1de3b001dd

I've created a simple 'movie' model

I've added `gem 'graphql'`

Ran `Bundle Install`

Ran  `rails g graphql:install`

Ran `Bundle Install`

I've then updated `query_type.rb` to:

```
 Types::QueryType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
    name “Query”
    # Add root-level fields here.
    # They will be entry points for queries on your schema.
    field :allMovies do
      type types[Types::MovieType]
      description “A list of all the movies”

      resolve -> (obj, args, ctx) {
        Movie.all
      }
    end

    field :movie do
      type Types::MovieType
      description “Return a movie”
      argument :id, !types.ID
      resolve -> (obj, args, ctx) { Movie.find(args[:id]) }
    end   
end
```

`movie_type.rb` looks like:

```
module Types
  class MovieType < Types::BaseObject
    name “Movie”

    field :id, !types.ID
    field :title, !types.String
    field :description, types.String
  end
end
```

However, when I start the server and go to `localhost:3000/graphql` I get the following message.`"GraphQL::ObjectType can't define '“Query”'"`

Something I've noticed is that when I initially open `query_type.rb` it has the following code that none of the tutorials I've seen online make any reference to:

```
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
end
end
```

The code doesn't work if I add code within this, nor does it work if I totally replace as per above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I pasted the wrong damn quotes:

`description “A list of all the movies”`

should of course be:

`description "A list of all the movies"`

Yes, I know I'll learn better by typing out the code, so consider myself learned.